# unable to deploy web service on netbeans 6.8

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, apache-axis

I'm trying to deploy  a web service using `tomcat` ,`axis2` and `netbeans 6.8` but i get this message:

> C:\Users\Fa\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaLibrary4\nbproject\axis2-build.xml:38:
>   Could not create tempfile in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

what does this means please?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot specifically give an answer but it seems like the file creation fails due to a permission issue. Try to run the Netbeans with the Administrator privileges or give write permission to the webapps folder.